# Finding all aliases for a server via Java code

Tags: java, networking

I have faced with inability to find all aliases for a domain name using [InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html). Is there any way to grep them through Java in order to accomplish  matching the results getting after the execution of `nslookup domain_name` via cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way to do this is to use native command line lookup though java Runtime class and further parse the cmd result string as in the below example

```
 private static String execCmd(String cmd) {
    java.util.Scanner s = s = new java.util.Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : StringUtils.EMPTY;
}
```